# How to fetch records from table with different types without breaking SOLID

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Let's say I have notification in different formats e.g.

> {UserName} tagget you in a comment in {ClientName}'s account.
>
> Client {ClientName} is waiting for approval.

and so on. I want to keep messages in database with placeholders and when listing them dynimacly to replace placeholders with corresponding name coming from right table.
So for above examples my table would have the following columns:

```
Message: string
Type: enum [OnePlaceholder, TwoPlaceholders]
UserId: int
ClientId: int
```

And when I fetch data from those table to display it I should check what type is every record and according to it to format the message.

```
var list = myTable.Select(m => {
    if(n.Type == OnePlaceholder)
        return new { Message = string.Format(n.Text, n.Client.Name) }
    else if(n.Type == TwoPlaceholder) 
        return new { Message = string.Format(n.Text, n.User.Name, n.Client.Name) }
}.ToList();
```

But that's obviously not a good solution. Also it breakes the SOLID principes because if there is new type of notification message I should first add new column in table and then add the else if check when fetching all notification.
So the question is what you could suggest me?

Comment: Anything in the Message column already contains placeholders for your actual values. Why not write something which scans the message for placeholders and then replace these with the appropriate values. You could use regualar expressions for this.

Comment: Because it's same, it doesn't matter whether I use column type to recognize how many placeholders the message have or scan it with regex.. Imagine if I have messsages with up to 30 placeholders, should I have 30 if statments? Also the order for placeholders could be different for every format/type.

Comment: Let me clarify. Drop the Type, UserId and ClientId columns, any new notification could introduce new columns containing id's, something you don't want. Alter the placeholders in the text to specify which table and id, and perhaps the property of target table, to use within the placeholder. This could look like "User {person#1234} logged in.". Write code to replace placeholders with actual values using the information in the placeholders.

Comment: @Dbuggy That's sounds like a good solution. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't help myself in making up something 'quick' which in my humble opinion is something SOLID for you to extend upon.

Lets start with the some data, which would normally be retrieved from the database in a way. So notifications in the next part would be retrieved from a database.

```
var notifications = new[] {
    "{user#1} tagged you in a comment in {client#1}'s account.",
    "Client {client#1} is waiting for approval.",
    "{user#2} assigned workitem {workitem#5} to {user#1}."
};
```

The only thing we are concerned here is that the placeholders will be replaced by values according to what is within the placeholders. So we need something which can substitute the placeholders with values. Lets define something for it which can do that.

```
public interface IPlaceHolderProcessor
{
    string SubstitutePlaceHolders(string text);
}
```

This allows me to write the following to handle the notifications.

```
IPlaceHolderProcessor processor = CreatePlaceHolderProcessor();
List<string> messages = notifications.Select(x => processor.SubstitutePlaceHolders(x)).ToList();
```

So that's all... well we do need to write an implementation for the interface. Well lets write an implementation which is extensible... and testable.

```
public class PlaceHolderProcessor : IPlaceHolderProcessor
{
    IPlaceHolderValueProvider _valueProvider;
    IPlaceHolderParser _parser;

    public PlaceHolderProcessor(IPlaceHolderValueProvider valueProvider, IPlaceHolderParser parser)
    {
        _valueProvider = valueProvider;
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public string SubstitutePlaceHolders(string message)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var idx = 0;
        var placeHolders = _parser.FindPlaceHolders(message);
        _valueProvider.PreFillValues(placeHolders);
        foreach (var placeholder in placeHolders)
        {
            sb.Append(message.Substring(idx, placeholder.Start - idx));
            idx = placeholder.End;
            sb.Append(_valueProvider.GetValue(placeholder));
        }
        sb.Append(message.Substring(idx));
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public interface IPlaceHolderValueProvider
{
    string GetValue(PlaceHolder placeholder);

    void PreFillValues(IEnumerable<PlaceHolder> placeholders);
}

public interface IPlaceHolderParser
{
    IEnumerable<PlaceHolder> FindPlaceHolders(string text);
}
```

This implementation only implements the find an replace. How scanning the text works or how the values are obtained is not something this implementation cares about. It only knows that the parser will return the placeholders and that the value provider will provide values to replace the placeholders with. The processors only task is to produce a string in which placeholders are replaced with the right values.

So lets start by making a simple parser...

```
public class DefaultPlaceHolderParser : IPlaceHolderParser
{
    public IEnumerable<PlaceHolder> FindPlaceHolders(string text)
    {
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\{)([^\}]+)(?=\})"))
        {
            yield return new PlaceHolder { Start = match.Index - 1, End = match.Index + match.Length + 1, Name = match.Value };
        }
    }
}
```

Placeholders are now returned by this IPlaceHolderParser implementation. Next step is replacing them with values. So we need an implementation of the IPlaceHolderValueProvider. Lets define an implementation for this.

```
public abstract class PlaceHolderValueProviderBase : IPlaceHolderValueProvider
{
    public abstract string GetValue(PlaceHolder placeholder);

    public virtual void PreFillValues(IEnumerable<PlaceHolder> placeholders) { }
}

public class DefaultPlaceHolderValueProvider : PlaceHolderValueProviderBase
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _cache;

    public DefaultPlaceHolderValueProvider()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public override string GetValue(PlaceHolder placeholder)
    {
        if (!_cache.ContainsKey(placeholder.Name))
        {
            _cache[placeholder.Name] = InternalGetValue(placeholder.Name);
        }
        return _cache[placeholder.Name];
    }

    public override void PreFillValues(IEnumerable<PlaceHolder> placeholders)
    {
        // Use an optimized way of retrieving placeholder values and fill the _cache
    }

    private string InternalGetValue(string placeHolder)
    {
        var values = placeHolder.Split('#');
        var entity = values[0];
        var id = int.Parse(values[1]);

        // Here you would hit the database to get a single placeholder value.

        return $"[{entity}{id:000}]";
    }
}
```

This implementation will not hit the database, it provides hopefully enough pointers to see what is happening here. You may use this as a base line for your own implementation.

Btw.. i forgot something. The CreatePlaceHolderProcessor method which is just a simple factory method to create a suitable IPlaceHolderProcessor implementation. In my case i used the following.

```
public IPlaceHolderProcessor CreatePlaceHolderProcessor()
{
    var valueProvider = new DefaultPlaceHolderValueProvider();
    var processor = new PlaceHolderProcessor(valueProvider, new DefaultPlaceHolderParser());
    return processor;
}
```

This provides a workable and extendable (SOLID) solution. If you got questions/remarks regarding this setup feel free to message me.

Hope this helps you and others a bit.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks you so much for great solution :p

Comment: In DefaultPlaceHolderValueProvider how I should access the database? Because I have to register those class as a service so the DbContext could be able to be injected into the constructor.

Comment: You could inject the DbContext into the DefaultPlaceHolderValueProvider and build up the value provider within the service method.